# Having trouble creating a mock context in Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I have my context, which contains things such as:

```
public partial class MyEntities : DbContext
{
    ...
    public DbSet<Cat> Cats { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to mock it.

I create another partial class that implements an interface I make called `IContext`.

I have to put into this interface

```
public interface IContext
{
    DbSet<Cat> Cats { get; set; }
}
```

Then I can create a mock and everyone is happy.

Except I don't want to be using `DbSet<Cat>` in my interface. That seems wrong, since I won't be using a database. Is there some way to change it, or a better solution? Obviously the context is autogenerated from a template so I can't edit it without it being lost on regeneration.

I'm not really sure how to proceed in creating a mock context. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way.

You can return [IDbSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679233%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) instead of DbSet and then in mock setup you can provide mocked IDbSet  as return value from Cats property in your mocked IContext.

```
public interface IContext
{
  IDbSet<Cat> Cats{get;set;}
}
public partial class MyEntities : DbContext , IContext
{
    public IDbSet<Cat> Cats { get; set; }
}
```

But maybe even better, in your interface don't introduce property for every entity class. Insted your IDbContext could be only:

```
public interface IContext
{
   IDbSet<T> Set<T>();
}
```

that you can query with

```
var query = dbContext.Set<Cat>().Where(....)
```

This way you should have no problem to "mock" it.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can change `DbSet<Cat>` to `IDbSet<Cat>` because `DbSet<Cat>` exists in the auto-generated `MyEntities` class

Comment: Not sure how you are autogenerating. If you are using T4 template for that, you could modify it, should not be a big problem. You could still go with T Set<T>(). But that will require that you write your queries differently, without using DbContext set properties.

Comment: @jure Do you mean `IDbSet<T> Set<T>();`? Just `T` for the return type would mean `Set<Cat>()` returns a `Cat`.

Comment: @grantman16 Yes, that was the idea. Edited, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: the generic IDbSet<T> Set<T>(); gives me the error: "The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet<TEntity>'"

Comment: @Ozz you should include where T:class contraint on the generic type. IDbSet<T> Set<T>() where T:class;